# My Chrome on Mac (with Mac OS Sierra) always starts with feed.snowbitt.com when I run it

Tags: google-chrome, malware, virus, anti-virus

I always get redirected to site feed.snowbitt.com when I run my Chrome. I tried to:
-Delete Chrome from computer, and reinstall it. Didn' work.
-Clear all my content, browsing history from Chrome. Didn't work.
-I tried some free antivirus programs to scan my cimputer. Didn't work.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Chrome > Preferences... by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> or by typing **chrome://settings/** into the Address Bar.

Under the **On start-up** settings, make sure you have selected **Open the New Tab page** and not some specific page, which in your case is: "feed.snowbitt.com"

[image]

Comment: I tried that too, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by signing off on my Google Chrome account on Chrome, uninstalling Chrome, and reinstalling again. Then signing in then.

Comment: Did you sign back in then? No redirection then?

Comment: I unsigned from Chrome, reinstalled Chrome, and signed in to Chrome account. I don't know what you mean by redirection.

Comment: In your question you wrote: "I always get redirected" - that is what I am asking about. After re-installing Chrome did your problem disappear?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is the standard opening page option referred to above but I this can also have to do with an extension, some spam-like setting. Search for that.